# Forge Viewer - Visual Styles

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was using API version 6.4* to changed visual styles of models showed in Forge viewer. I was using this syntax:

```
this.viewer.impl.setPostProcessParameter("style", "graphite");
this.viewer.impl.setPostProcessParameter("brightness", 0);
this.viewer.impl.setPostProcessParameter("edges", true);
```

And when I now use API version 7.*, I can´t use that syntax. Is it any other solution for change visual styles?

Thanks

M.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v7 the non-photo realistic rendering has been moved to extension `Autodesk.NPR`. See the [migration guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Peter. That work it. But that update API 7.* is bad. I must re-write much function :-(

Comment: There's quite a few breaking changes, I agree. If it's too much work for you at the moment, I'd suggest that you stick with 6.* (i.e., using something like `<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v6.*"></script>`), and later on, when you're ready to migrate, open up the migration guide and update the code accordingly.